# Parse_url and ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])

Tags: php, url

I´m trying to pick up the correct path with `parse_url` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in order to show the correct page, however the problem I´m having is that only my `index.php` page is showing.

The url to my `index.php` page should be `localhost/mvc-framework` which is all correct, but when I take:
`localhost/mvc-framework/file.php` it is also showing my `index.php`. Basically anything I type in after somefolder also show the `index.php` page...

*I really hope someone can help me out as I´ve been struggling with this for almost 3 hole days.* 
I´m probably stupid:/

I have all files in "mvc-framework" and inside I have one `index.php` file that ties everything together and 3 folders: "controller", "model", "views".

In controller folder I have one file called main.php which is were I´m trying to pick up the url:

```
<?php
/* controller/main.php
 */
class mainController
{
    public $load;
    public $urlValues;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $url = explode('/', $url['path']);  
        $this->urlValues = array('controller' => $url[1]);

        //index page
        if ($this->urlValues['controller'] == "mvc-framework") {

        $text = array("key" => "Hello");

        $this->load = new load();
        $this->load->view('index.php', $text);   
        }

        //register page
        elseif ($this->urlValues['controller'] == "mvc-framework/test.php") {

        $text = array("key" => "Test");

        $this->load = new load();
        $this->load->view('test.php', $text);   
        } else {
            echo 'error';
        }

    }        
}
```

In the "model" folder I have one file called load.php which will take the url and point it to the the correct file in the views folder...

```
<?php
/* model/load.php
 */
class load
{

    /* This function takes parameter 
     * $file_name and match with file in views.
     */

    function view($file_name, $data = null)
    {
        if (is_readable('views/' . $file_name)) {
            if (is_array($data)) {
                extract($data);
            }

            require 'views/' . $file_name;
        } else {
             echo $this->file;
                die ('404 Not Found');
        }
    }

}
```

In the views folder I have 2 files, one index.php and one test.php...

And here is my bootstrap/index.php file which is in the root folder and bind everything together...

```
<?php
/* index.php
 */

require_once 'model/load.php';
require_once 'controller/main.php';

new mainController();
```

Comment: `parse_url( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], PHP_URL_PATH )` PHP Version 5.3+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

> $url = explode('/', trim($url['path'], '/'));

and $this->urlValues['controller'] == 'test.php' for request localhost/mvc-framework/test.php

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!! THANK YOU! This was it! I didn´t think trim was the right solution as I thought it removed the path....

Comment: Just a question as I had to change $this->urlValues['controller'] == 'index.php' as well in order to get the index page to load. How can I make the index.php show up when only entering the localhost/mvc-framework/ folder without having to type index.php after?

Comment: You can check your $url[1] if empty or index.php is index controller. Or you want to see index.php in url? If yes, try do redirect to localhost/mvc-framework/index.php

Answer (score 0):

You always get the index.php beacuse of the .htaccess file, which always redirect the request to the frontend controller, index.php. I suppose...

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment! The url does not change though if I type in another file it looks ok in the url... This is what I have in my .htaccess file: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php

Comment: This rule (RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php) says that everything without that extensions should be redirected to your index.php; Try requesting file.php or file.css and u'll note the differences.

Comment: But it´s directing to my index.php file in the root folder. The file that binds everything together... The file that is showing is my index.php file inside views folder...